# darktable 4.0, favorites category missing?

Tags: darktable

Upgraded my OSs (FreeBSD and Ubuntu) and apps, now running darktable 4.0.

In darkroom, the only tabs I see on the right now are

```
quick-access
active
technical
grading
effects
```

Is there a way to get the equivalent of the old "favorites" back?  It's a real pain to have to switch between the various tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darktable 4.0 doesn't have a *Favorites* per se, but you can add a custom module and name it anything you like.

[Darktable 4.0 User Manual: manage module layouts](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.0/en/darkroom/organization/manage-module-layouts/)

Ctrl-click the 3 horizonal lines (*I believe that symbol is commonly referred to as a **Hamburger***) to the far right of the module lists in "darkroom".